# VPN program alternative to windows build in solution

Tags: windows, gratis, vpn

I am using a synology NAS that has a L2TP/Ipsec VPN server running.
On debian and android the connection works great. But on Windows 10 it is a 50/50 game if it will work or not.

I tried a lot of things to get it work but sometimes it is nearly impossible.
And because windows is not reliable in that point, I thought I could try a alternative to the build in windows VPN client.
A program, that can establish the L2TP/Ipsec vpn connection.

But the programs i find (freelan, softether, ...) have all theire own server runtimes as well.

So what programs for windows are out there, that can connect to a existing L2TP/Ipsec vpn? Any suggestions?

quick overview:
price: free
os: windows 10
purpose: connect to an existing L2TP/Ipsec VPN Server that is hosted on a synology NAS

thanks and greetings

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ShrewSoft VPN](https://www.shrew.net/download/vpn) client under Standard Edition, which is free, I have used it in the past without any issues. It supports L2TP/IPSec.

Please make sure that you select the Standard Edition, during the set up instead of the Professional, as the professional requires a license after 14 days.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation. But the newest release is from 2013 and so I am not fully convinced.

Comment: We've used it extensively with a lot of users with not issues. A try might convince you.

Comment: ok, I try it. Thanks a lot.  But after installing the program, the gui confuses me. I found the spot to put the preshared key, but where does the username and password go? I don't find input fields.

Comment: When you configure your connection then you double click on it and you will be prompted to type in your username and password

Comment: thanks for the help so far. But I do not get a connection at all. I posted all my configurations below. Maybe you could help me? that would be so nice.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `ShredSoft VPN` like [sonamor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/15112/sonamor) recommendet.
So far it seems like a basic program with a lot of functions and no modern bad designed UI. So nothing confusing.

But I have problems connecting with it to my VPN. And the hole point of using a third party program instead of the Windows 10 build in VPN module is, that it should work.

When I connect, I always get a log like this:

```
config loaded for site 'testVPN'
attached to key daemon ...
peer configured
iskamp proposal configured
esp proposal configured
client configured
local id configured
remote id configured
pre-shared key configured
bringing up tunnel ...
negotiation timout occurred
tunnel disabled
detached from key daemon
```

And the line `negotiation timout occurred` is red.

So here are all my configs:

In the router, that is in the network of the VPN Server, the Ports `1701`, `500` and `4500` are opened to the VPN Server. All `UDP`.

The VPN Server is a Synology NAS that has the following configuration:
[image: Synology NAS VPN Server configuration]

And my ShrewSoft software has the following configurations:
[image: ShrewSoft configuration]

And with this settings I get the log from above.

Like I already mentiond:
With other Windows 10 computers I can connect, also with my Android 7 phone.

As an example, here are the configs of the Android 7 phone:
[image: Android 7 VPN configuration]

So what am I missing in this recommendet program?
If it will not run, I maybe need an other program. But so far ShrewSoft makes a good impression, but only an impression so far ...

thanks for any help and greetings.